# storing a rendered element in a variable in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am having some trouble trying to "capture" the rendered html of an elmenet in cake php.

Say I have an element named "message.ctp"

I would like to do something like the following:

A making a $.getJSON request to an action in a controller say jsonAction(). Within this action I will perform some DB updates and return a json string. I would like to store the html is a part of the json object. Doable?

```
function jsonAction() {
    //Do DB update
    if(db update was ok) {
        $response = array("completed" => true, "html" => $this->render("message"));
    } else {
       $response = array("completed" => false);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

What seems to be happening right now is that the render method echos the rendered value instead of returning it.

Anyway I can achieve this?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Comment: Check the autoRender variable value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$myRenderedHtml = $this->element('message');
                         ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can that method be called within a controller action?

Comment: No, elements are not supposed to be rendered from a controller. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @deceze I have updated the question to explain better what I would like to acheive.

Comment: @ElGabbu Why don't you do the view stuff (creating JSON + HTML output) in the view? You shouldn't do that in the controller, be it an AJAX request or not.

Comment: hmmm I could ... from the controller create the array with the completed key ... use the $this->set("response", $response); .... Then in the view check if $response["completed"] is true and if so add the element's rendered html ... then echo json_encode($response); ... should do the trick you think? I will give it a shot later. Thanks!

Comment: @ElGabbu That's always the better way to do it! Ideally you should be able to reuse your controller actions as-is and swap out views depending on what's requested. So don't return values directly to the client from a controller action, always go through a view.

Comment: Swapping out views ... you mean use different views to for example return different json objects depending on what is being requested? ... I have some other actions which return values directly they literaly just return a json_encode(true / false) depending on the result of a DB operation should I still have a view returning the json string?

Comment: @ElGabbu I mean that the same controller action could render an HTML view, a JSON view, an XML view or whatever other format is required. This can all happen automatically based on HTTP headers in the request. This is only possible though by decoupling the data the action manipulates from how this data is rendered. That's (among other things) the point of an MVC architecture.

Comment: @deceze ... hey mate just wanted to let you know that it worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Forget elements for the time being.

First of all you have to separate everything that includes outputting stuff from the controller (either it is HTML or JSON or whatever).

For every controller action you have to have a corresponding view. So, for controller action `jsonAction` you should have a view names `json_action.ctp` (at the corresponding folder, e.g. if `jsonAction` is at `MessagesController` create a folder named `/view/messages/json_action.ctp`).

Set your variable from controller, display it at view and you are done. Do not forget to `$this->layout = 'empty'` from controller so that you display only what you have at the view.

Generally you should redo the CakePHP tutorials and reread the book it order to understand better the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern and CakePHP structure.